# upload pipe delimited data into azure blob storage

Tags: c#

I am tring to use csvhelper to create a pipe delimited string and upload into azure blob storage as .csv file.

The data has comma in the value like following

```
Column1|Column2|Column3
Text1|Text2, with comma|Text3
```

But after uploaded to blob and download and open locally, the column2 value separated by the comma.

At the end, Header in one cell, and value in 3 cell.

How can i make the blob storage read the file as comma separated file?

```
public static string ProcessDataToCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = "|",
            };

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(data);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
```

```
public async Task<string> PersistDataAsync(string fileName, string data) 
       {
               var containerName = _configuration.BlobContainerName;
               var targetFilename = fileName;
               var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
               var targetFullBlobPath = $"{_configuration.PathToSaveBlobs}\\{targetFilename}_{timestamp}.csv"; ;

               var blobClient = GetBlobClient(containerName, targetFullBlobPath);

               var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataPerIsins);
               using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dataBytes))
               {
                   await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, true);
               }

               return "save success";

       }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added code, please help.